# How specifically do I need to describe (in words) the language of a regular expression?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

For the regular expression $(a^*ba^*b)^*a^*$, I want to learn how to describe it in words. I know there are an even number of $b$s but how much do I need to explain it? Do I need to explain it enough that each possible string can be produced from my explanation?
Another example is $(a^*[ba^*c])^*$ where I would describe it as as string over $\{a,b,c\}$ where there are the same number of $a$s and $c$s.

Comment: This sounds to me like a question about the English language, not a technical question about computer science.  As far as "how much do you need to explain it", that depends on what purpose you want your description to serve, so that does not seem answerable with the information provided.  What do others think?  Is this on-topic here?  Any community votes? (I suggest you ask your instructor.)

Comment: Does $(a*ba*b)*a*$ need to be told from $a*(ba*ba*)*$: do you need to describe *regular **expressions*** or *regular **languages***?

Comment: (Second one is *sequence of $bc$s, with interspersed $a$s, optionally preceded, but not followed by a run of $a$s*.) (You intended *same number of $\textbf b$s and $c$s*…)

Comment: thank you for the guidance. My professor has asked us to avoid paraphrasing. So it looks like greybear has a good way of avoiding that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first language can be described as the set of words on the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ with an even number of $b$'s.

The second one is **not** the language of words on the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ with an equal number of $b$'s and $c$'s (this condition would define a non-regular language). You could use greybeard's description or say: the language contains the empty word, the last letter of the nonempty words of the language is a $c$ and if you delete the $a$'s, you are in $(bc)^*$.

It would be safe to provide a formal proof by computing the minimal automaton corresponding to each description.